# admob test banner ad shows in emulator android 11 but not in Galaxy S10 Android 11

Tags: android, flutter, admob, banner-ads

i'm building a flutter App which i am monetizing through Ad mob.
i'm specifically using the banner Ads for now.

but here is my issue.
in my simulator, i can see the test banners in Android 9 and Android 11
i can even see them in a real Xiaomi Android 9.
but on a Galaxy S10 i can't see them.

i already tried to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

have you ever experienced a discrepancy like this ?
how can i debug in a real device?

EDIT:

so i connected to the device by pairing it via Wi-Fi and i got

UseRequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("0E9819CC3AEA7F45DCB97C80DCE78CF6")) to get test ads on this device.

thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your phone to be recognized as a test device. Add the below lines in your method that you load the ad. In addition to a simulator device that doesn't need this clarification.
 `List<String> testDevices = ['0E9819CC3AEA7F45DCB97C80DCE78CF6'];`

```
MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(
        RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: testDevices));
```